# Can not access underlying object of a Mock

Tags: c#, wpf, moq

I have the following code in a unit test where I am using `Moq`:

```
Mock<BorderedCanvas> canvas2 = new Mock<BorderedCanvas>();
canvas2.Object.Children.Add(canvas1);
canvas1.RaiseEvent(someEvent);
canvas2.Verify(c => c.RaiseEvent(It.IsAny<RoutedEventArgs>()), Times.Once);
```

The code fails on the second line with this message:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any idea why I can not access the underlying object of the mock `canvas2`?

Comment: `Children` is null

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to understand how to use the framework and why you get null.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why is `Children` null? If you instantiate a `new BorderedCanvas()`, its `Children` field will not be null.

Comment: Then why are you using a mock to begin with? just create an instance and use that. If `Children` is virtual, moq will override it and return null by default unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: As it is shown in the last line of my code, I am using a mock because I want to check if one of the methods of the underlying object is called.

Comment: mocks should be used to mock dependencies of the subject under test, not to mock the subject of the test.

Comment: `canvas2` is not the subject under test. `canvas1` is

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties and see if it helps. specifically `mock.SetupAllProperties();`

Answer (score 1):

Everything about the mock object will return default values unless you have told it to behave otherwise. Since you haven't told it how the Children property should behave, it is returning the default value for that type, which is null. Hence the NullReferenceException when you try to call "Add" on a null object. (Wow, beaten to it by multiple comments, above...)